# Как настроить автоматический запуск упавшего приложения?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, dokku

Есть Rails приложение и Dokku (Docker).

Начали возникать ситуации, когда судя по всему не хватает оперативной памяти на сервере. Вместе с контейнером Rails приложения стартуют еще PostgreSQL и Redis.

Я понимаю что нужно решать проблему с ОЗУ, но также я хотел бы решить еще одну проблему - автоматический перезапуск упавшего приложения (или правильнее контейнеров?)

Первый раз, когда упало приложение, в логах на последней строке я обнаружил слово `Killed`. На моей практике это всегда было из-за нехватки ОЗУ.

Сегодня в логе на последней строке я вижу `Completed 200 OK` от `ActiveRecord`. До этой строки тоже не было внятных ошибок. То есть шли запросы от пользователей. И с тех пор приложение "лежало".

Читая документацию Dokku и Docker, наткнулся на Restart policies. А если конкретно, то на `on-failure`. У Dokku это 10 изначально.

Но я честно скажу, что я не совсем понял, как оно работает, ибо желаемого перезапуска не происходит.

Не могли бы вы, пожалуйста, дать советы по этой теме, ибо она для меня совсем нова?

**ОБНОВЛЕНИЕ**

Сейчас в очередной раз произошел сбой. Судя по логам шла обычная работа сайта, а потом бац и:

```
2018-01-27T00:02:18.007071654Z app[web.1]: worker| 17 TID-4f6c3uxc ERROR: Error fetching job: Connection timed out
2018-01-27T00:02:18.079508449Z app[web.1]: worker| 17 TID-4f6c3uxc ERROR: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/redis-4.0.1/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:71:in `rescue in _read_from_socket'
2018-01-27T00:02:18.195528089Z app[web.1]: worker| 17 TID-4f6c3uxc ERROR: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/redis-4.0.1/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:64:in `_read_from_socket'
2018-01-27T00:02:18.211610150Z app[web.1]: worker| 17 TID-4f6c3uxc ERROR: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/redis-4.0.1/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:56:in `gets'
# И так далее...
```

Только что поймал одну строку:

```
2018-01-27T13:22:43.346159095Z app[web.1]: Killed
```

Answer (score 2):

Не знаю точно, как работает dokku, но должно быть достаточно установки restart-policy = always на стороне докера (dokku скорее всего это пробрасывает в идентичном виде). Сам on-failure у вас может не работать из-за того, что вы указываете 10 перезапусков, но не указываете саму restart-policy, которая не является on-failure (из текста поста не очень понятно, как происходит конфигурирование).

Comment: Да, dokku по этой теме идентичен docker (то есть конфигуриются по факту именно контейнеры). Сделаю как вы написали и посмотрю что будет дальше.

Answer (score 0):

Если нужен авто рестарт можно глянуть в сторону [супервизора](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/).

Comment: Это актуально для многопроцессных контейнеров, что идёт поперёк идиом Docker и в этом вопросе неактуально.